# How do you display an image with a source attached to an object? The object (question) is selected randomly and images should change with them

Tags: javascript, image, object, random

I have an array of objects which are questions.  This is for a random question quiz.  Basically, when one question is randomly selected, I thought all of the attributes would go with it (if "called" correctly).  I am not sure how to display the image from the object when the question text (q) displays.

```
const questionBank = [
{
    q: "This is question 1's text",
    options:['1','2','3','4', '5'],
    answer:4,
    imgURL: 'http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=googleDriveId',
},
{
    q: "question 2 will go here",
    options:['7','6','4'],
    answer:0,
    imgURL: 'http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=differentDriveId',
}

function getNewQuestion(){
    const question = document.querySelector(".question");

    //set question text
    question.innerHTML = currentQuestion.q;

    //add image to question 
    //document.querySelector('.question').appendChild(img); (attempted, did not work)
    //var img = new Image(); (attempted, did not work)
    //img = document.createElement("img");  (attempted, did not work)
    //img.src = document.querySelector('.imgUrl'); (attempted, did not work)
```

I think that is all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with creating a new img element, if you take a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-image-element-dynamically-using-javascript/) post, you need to create a new image element.

on your last line, instead set `image.src = currentQuestion.imgURL` as you want the current questions imgURL property, then you can [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) your new image element!

Comment: Appreciate the help.  For those who stumble on this in the future, the final snippet of code looks like this:                                                                                                                  
        //add image to question
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = currentQuestion.imgURL
 document.querySelector('.question').appendChild(img);